# Using a pointer to use previous element in a vector of doubles

Tags: c++, r, r-lib-cpp11

Regarding R and C++ communication: Is there a way to use a pointer and be able to compile a simple code to imitate the `cummin()` function from base R?

This works

```cpp
#include <cpp11.hpp>

using namespace cpp11;
namespace writable = cpp11::writable;

[[cpp11::register]] cpp11::doubles cummin_cpp_(cpp11::doubles x) {
  int n = x.size();

  // create a vector of 0s
  writable::doubles out(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    out[i] = 0.0;
  }

  out[0] += x[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (x[i] < out[i - 1]) {
      out[i] += x[i];
    } else {
      out[i] += out[i - 1];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

However,

1. It fill with 0s
2. Then does 0 + x, 0 + y, ..., 0 + z99 by using `+=`

What I have been trying is something such as

```cpp
[[cpp11::register]] cpp11::doubles cummin_cpp_(cpp11::doubles x) {
  int n = x.size();

  writable::doubles out(n);

  out[0] = x[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (x[i] < out[i - 1]) {
      out[i] = x[i];
    } else {
      // code.cpp:157:18: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘cpp11::writable::r_vector<double>::proxy’)
      out[i] = &(*out[i - 1]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Which follows this logic

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int one() {
  int x = 1;
  int* y = &x;
  cout << "y: " << *y << endl;
  return *y;
}

int main() { return one(); }
```

@War's approach below, translated to my case is

```cpp
[[cpp11::register]] cpp11::doubles cummin_cpp_(cpp11::doubles x) {
  int n = x.size();
  writable::doubles out(n);

  out[0] = x[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    out[i] = std::min(out[i - 1], x[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

which returns

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to ‘min(cpp11::writable::r_vector<double>::proxy, double)’
     150 |     out[i] = std::min(out[i - 1], x[i]);
```

Comment: thanks! I edited to add one of my many fails with the actual pointer

Comment: The simple `out[i] = out[i-1]` returns `error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘cpp11::writable::r_vector<double>::proxy’ and ‘cpp11::writable::r_vector<double>::proxy’)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a vector by value that has the results of the cummin operation

Here's an example from [here](https://advanced-r-solutions.rbind.io/rewriting-r-code-in-c.html):

```
NumericVector cumminC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);

  out[0] = x[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    out[i]  = std::min(out[i - 1], x[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Regarding the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘min(cpp11::writable::r_vector<double>::proxy, double)’
     150 |     out[i] = std::min(out[i - 1], x[i]);
```

std::min expects both arguments to be the same type. You could either make the types the same or write your own min function that takes the respective types.

Comment: Elegant! I included the translation in my question. It returns an error.

Comment: *Your function one() returns a dereferenced pointer (*y) to stack allocated x which is out of scope at the end of the function which leads to undefined behavior.* This is not true.

Comment: As pointed out by @273K, the ``one()`` function doesn't return a dereferenced pointer, as it returns ``*y`` and not ``y``. ``*y`` reads the value at pointer ``y``, which is still valid at the time of ``return``'ing. The ``one()`` function returns a value, which, in this case, is ``1``.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake - the one() function did indeed return 1 at end of scope.